# Positive elements are relative to the page, not the parent React component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a DeleteWindow Rect-component that resides in a Post component. I want the element window to be centered on the screen, not centered on the parent component. I used all my knowledge of css to position relative to the screen, but the component is still positioned relative to the parent component and cannot go beyond it. Tell me how to fix this situation

```
import React from 'react';
import {postApi} from "./../utils/api"
import {DeleteWindow} from "./DeleteWindow"

export class Post extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            onDelete: false
        }
        this.removePost = this.removePost.bind(this);
        this.redactPost = this.redactPost.bind(this);
        this.callbackRemove = this.callbackRemove.bind(this);
    }

    removePost(){
        this.setState({onDelete: true});
    }

    callbackRemove(isRemove){
        this.setState({onDelete: false});
        if(isRemove)
            this.props.onRemove(this.props.id);
    }

    redactPost(){
        postApi.setUpdatePost({id: this.props.id, title: this.props.title, text: this.props.text, author: this.props.author}).then(window.location.assign("/redactPost"));
    }

    render() {
        function EditButton(props){
            if (props.admin){
                return(
                    <>
                        <h className="editButton" onClick={props.redactPost}>
                            Изменить
                        </h>
                        <h className="removeButton" onClick={props.removePost}>
                            Удалить
                        </h>
                    </>
                );
            }
            return null;
        }

        function DeleteBlock(props){
            if (props.onDelete)
                return <DeleteWindow onDelete={props.onDelete} callbackRemove={props.callbackRemove}/>
            return null;
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <DeleteBlock onDelete={this.state.onDelete} callbackRemove={this.callbackRemove}/>
                <hr/>
                <div className="post">
                    <p className="titlePost">{this.props.title}</p>
                    <p className="textPost">{this.props.text}</p>
                    <p className="author">{this.props.author}</p>
                    <p className="center">
                        <p>
                            <i className="date">{this.props.date}</i>
                            <EditButton admin={this.props.admin} redactPost={this.redactPost} removePost={this.removePost}/>
                        </p>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}




import React from 'react';

export class DeleteWindow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.clickYes = this.clickYes.bind(this);
        this.clickNo = this.clickNo.bind(this);
    }

    clickYes(){
        this.props.callbackRemove(true);
    }

    clickNo(){
        this.props.callbackRemove(false);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="deleteBlock">
                <p>Вы действительно хотите удалить этот пост?</p>
                <button className="deleteWindowButton" onClick={this.clickYes}>Да</button>
                <button className="deleteWindowButton" onClick={this.clickNo}>Нет</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



@media (min-width: 850px) {
    .deleteBlock {
        width: 40%;
        font-size: 16pt;
        margin-left: 30%;
    }

    .deleteWindowButton{
        width: 30%;
        font-size: 15pt;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 580px) {
    .deleteBlock {
        width: 60%;
        font-size: 14pt;
        margin-left: 20%;
    }

    .deleteWindowButton{
        width: 30%;
        font-size: 13pt;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 580px) and (min-width: 400px) {
    .deleteBlock {
        width: 80%;
        font-size: 13pt;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    .deleteWindowButton{
        width: 30%;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px){
    .deleteBlock {
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 12pt;
        margin-left: 5%;
    }

    .deleteWindowButton{
        width: 30%;
        font-size: 11pt;
    }
}

.deleteBlock{
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #676a6d;
    font-family: "Lucida Calligraphy", cursive;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
}

.deleteWindowButton{
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    outline: none;
}

.deleteWindowButton:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: I have added code, I want center DeleteBlock on page, but not on Post-component